# Actions of Actors in libgdx

Tags: android, action, actor, libgdx

I have made my [Actor](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html), but I am unclear on how to take advantage of the `action` and `act` methods.  Outside of the basic Javadoc, I have not found a good tutorials on these methods.

Can anyone provide an example with comments for actions on actors?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**This answer is being rendered obsolete because of changes in LibGDX. For up to date documentation see [scene2d wiki page](https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/scene2d/scene2d#actions).**

There are various available actions in LibGDX ready for you. They are in `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions` package. I would say that there are 3 kinds of actions:

1. Animation actions
2. Composite actions
3. Other actions

Animation actions modify various properties of your actor, such as location, rotation, scale and alpha. They are:

- FadeIn - changes alpha of your actor from actor's current alpha to 1
- FadeOut - changes alpha of your actor from actor's current alpha to 0
- FadeTo - changes alpha of your actor from actor's current alpha to specific value
- MoveBy - moves your actor *by* specific amount
- MoveTo - moves your actor *to* specific location
- RotateBy - rotates your actor *by* specific angle
- RotateTo - rotates your actor *to* specific angle
- ScaleTo - scales your actor to specific scale factor

Composite actions combine multiple actions in one action, there are:

- Parallel - execute given actions in parallel - all actions at once
- Sequence - execute given actions in sequence - one after another

Other actions:

- Repeat - repeats given action n-times
- Forever - repeats given action forever
- Delay - delays execution of given action for specific amount of time
- Remove - removes given Actor from stage

Every action has a static method `$` which creates instance of that Action.
Example of creating animation actions:

```
MoveTo move = MoveTo.$(200, 200, 0.5f); //move Actor to location (200,200) in 0.5 s
RotateTo rotate = RotateTo.$(60, 0.5f); //rotate Actor to angle 60 in 0.5 s
```

Example of creating more complex action sequence:

```
Sequence sequence = Sequence.$(
              MoveTo.$(200, 200, 0.5f), //move actor to 200,200
              RotateTo.$(90, 0.5f),     //rotate actor to 90°
              FadeOut.$(0.5f),          //fade out actor (change alpha to 0)
              Remove.$()                //remove actor from stage
            );
```

Animation actions also let you specify `Interpolator`. There are various implementations:

- AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator
- AccelerateInterpolator
- AnticipateInterpolator
- DecelerateInterpolator
- LinearInterpolator
- OvershootInterpolator

Interpolator Javadoc: An interpolator defines the rate of change of an animation. This allows the basic animation effects (alpha, scale, translate, rotate) to be accelerated, decelerated etc.
To set interpolator to your action:

```
action.setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.$());
```

When you have your action with interpolator ready, then you set that action to your actor:

```
actor.action(yourAction);
```

To actually execute all actions defined for actors on stage, you have to call stage.act(...) in your render method:

```
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
stage.draw();
```

Comment: Really nice, comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer :) it was really well explained

Answer (score 13):

You should give Universal Tween Engine a try. It's easy to use and really powerful... and it makes reading complex animations a walk in the park because all commands can be chained. See examples bellow.

**Steps:**

**1.** Download the library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/downloads/list)
**2.** Create an accesor class. You can save the time and grab the one I was using from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/meeq6eg5vp2cdfa/ActorAccessor.java).
**3.** In your Game class declare the TweenManager

```
    public static TweenManager tweenManager;
```

In the **create** method:

```
    tweenManager = new TweenManager();
```

In the **render** method:

```
    tweenManager.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

**4.** Use it however you want. Ex.
Move actor to position (100, 200) in 1.5 seconds with elastic interpolation:

```
Tween.to(actor, ActorAccesor.POSITION_XY, 1.5f)
     .target(100, 200)
     .ease(Elastic.INOUT)
     .start(tweenManager);
```

Create a complex sequence of animations:

```
Timeline.createSequence()
    // First, set all objects to their initial positions
    .push(Tween.set(...))
    .push(Tween.set(...))
    .push(Tween.set(...))

    // Wait 1s
    .pushPause(1.0f)

    // Move the objects around, one after the other
    .push(Tween.to(...))
    .push(Tween.to(...))
    .push(Tween.to(...))

    // Then, move the objects around at the same time
    .beginParallel()
        .push(Tween.to(...))
        .push(Tween.to(...))
        .push(Tween.to(...))
    .end()

    // And repeat the whole sequence 2 times
    .repeatYoyo(2, 0.5f)

    // Let's go!
    .start(tweenManager);
```

More details [here](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

UPDATE: replaced dead link

Answer (score 11):

Here is a useful link for the uses of Class [com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/class-use/Interpolation.html).
So for example, to create a moveTo ation with an effect you could simply use:

```
myActor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(100, 200, 0.7f, Interpolation.bounceOut));
```

If you set your Actions class import as static (you have to set it manually):

```
import static com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.*;
```

then, you can use your actions like this:

```
myActor.addAction(moveTo(100, 200, 0.7f, Interpolation.bounceOut));
```