# How to create animations and user interfaces in android?

Tags: android, interface, libgdx

For example: Like the game bejeweled. At the beginning the gems are falling down. At the end, the gems are slowing down and stopping.

How i can do like this effects and animations? I mean, i want to give the animations to another class, and when the animations are completed, i will forwarded to the main class.

Is there a good library for this effects or animations in android. Or what is that called? Tweening?

I also want to make animated User Interfaces?

I'm programming with LIBGDX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibGDX has its own action API. See [Actions of Actors in libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131554/actions-of-actors-in-libgdx/9142896#9142896)  to learn more.

There is also a nice tween library which you can use with LibGDX. See [Java universal tween engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help, but you could have a look at this open source framework which is a really good option to develop games in Android:

http://www.andengine.org/