# How to make a game object automatically move through another game object?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, physics, actor

I'm currently making a 2D side-scroller game, in which the main character has to go through tubes (game objects as Actors) to score. I know how to move the game objects (using act under the render method of each actor), but how do I move the main character so it goes through individual tubes? I'm trying to make it move automatically by forcing it to go through a sequence of x,y coordinates, but is there another way for this work?

Comment: You can see solution [here][1]. You are interesed by MoveTo Acction.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131554/actions-of-actors-in-libgdx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify coordinates step by step why not use Box2d physics engine build in LibGdx. By setting tube bounds you may easily limit player character motion.

Advantages:

1. Good performance
2. You are not responsible for collision logic
3. Easy to implement, and keep implementation clean: http://programmersweb.blogspot.com/2012/07/simple-libgdx-box2d-bouncing-ball.html
4. Editor to create bodies and levels in visual manner.